# Fake calling of a function with specific arguments in Sinon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I have been on this for quite long and maybe I'm just missing something but my research did not yield any results that would help me.

So my question is:

If I have some code like this:

```
shell.on('message', function (message) {
// do something
});
```

And I want to test it as if it had been called with a certain message (or even an error), could I somehow do that with Sinon? ( just putting the do something in an external function will only work to some degree so I do hope for an answer that at least has a way to fake-call `shell.on` to test if the inner function gets invoked).

The "shell" is an instance of the shell of the npm Package "Python-Shell"

Maybe it's not possible at all or maybe I'm just blind but any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `python-shell` instance is instance of an `EventEmitter`. So you can cause the `on` handler to fire by just emitting the message:

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

var pyshell = new PythonShell('my_script.py');

pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
    console.log("recieved", message);
});

pyshell.emit('message', "fake message?")
// writes: 'recieved fake message?'
```

You can also stub the instance with Sinon and call `yields` to call the callback:

```
const sinon = require('sinon')
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

var pyshell = new PythonShell('my_script.py');
var stub = sinon.stub(pyshell, "on");
stub.yields("test message")
// writes received test message to console

pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
    console.log("received", message);
});
```

This might be more useful if you don't want to prevent the default behavior when running a test.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer first of all it deserves a big upvote! I think I missunderstood how `yields` works ( I thought it just replaces the return value of the function to return the given argument whenever the stub gets called in the test but as of my understanding now `stub.yields` replaces it and additionally also calls the function right away). I stubbed it in my test now with `sinon.stub(PythonShell.prototype, "on")`, like I did e.g. with `"send"` but for some reason `codeInsidePyshellonSpy.calledOnce.should.be.true();` does not return true.

Comment: The first part works like a charm and just wrapping pyshell.emit in a function makes it awesome for using in my tests. I'll accept your answer therefor with many regards